# C# program Slowing down due to function

Tags: c#, arduino

I am writing a C# program to interface with an Arduino through a serial port and I have a function updateRPMs() that slows down the program so much it is unusable. It gets called every 1 second when it is used. The program runs a few PWM fans.

Here is the function:

```
private void updateRPMs()
    {
        TextBox[] RPMS = { Fan1RPM, Fan2RPM, Fan3RPM, Fan4RPM, Fan5RPM, Fan6RPM, Fan7RPM, Fan8RPM, Fan9RPM, Fan10RPM, Fan11RPM, Fan12RPM };
        List<String> sepData = new List<String>();
        if (CONNECTED)
        {
            String data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            // MessageBox.Show(data);

            sepData = (data.Split(';').ToList());


            if (sepData.Count == 12)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                    RPMS[i].Text = sepData[i];
                }
            }
            serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
        }

    }
```

This is something the Arduino would send to the program:

```
a840.00;b885.00;c0;d0;e0;f0;g1635.00;h2070.00;i0;j0;k0;l0
```

I know I can push this to a different thread but I am trying to have it update as soon as the timer fires.

I was wondering if there is anything I could change or if there was anything stupid I did. I am new to C# and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use Stopwatch in C# to check which code part is causing issue.

Comment: First of all what calls this function? Then, how often does the arduino send the data? Baud rate? And why don't you use the incoming data from serial buffer? And why are you using the `DiscardOutBuffer` function?

Comment: 1. I have a timer firing every 1 second calling the function. 2. every 500ms. 3. 9600. 4. Not sure what you mean? I thought that is what ReadLine did. 5. I guess if I am using ReadLine() I dont need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading from serial, I suggest you to avoid using a timer to read from the serial. You can use the `DataReceived` event, which is fired every time some data is received from the serial.

Of course you could receive a partial packet, so it's better to store the data in a buffer and then analyze it.

```
String readBuffer = "";

private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    readBuffer += sp.ReadExisting();

    int newLineIndex = -1;
    while ((newLineIndex = readBuffer.IndexOf("\n")) >= 0)
    { // Analyze buffer
        String currentLine = readBuffer.Substring(0,newLineIndex);
        if (currentLine.length() > 0)
            analyzeLine(currentLine);
        readBuffer = readBuffer.Substring(newLineIndex+1);
    }
}

public void analyzeLine(String data)
{
    static TextBox[] RPMS = { Fan1RPM, Fan2RPM, Fan3RPM, Fan4RPM, Fan5RPM, Fan6RPM, Fan7RPM, Fan8RPM, Fan9RPM, Fan10RPM, Fan11RPM, Fan12RPM };
    List<String> sepData = (data.Split(';').ToList());
    if (sepData.Count == 12)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            RPMS[i].Text = sepData[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you know how to attach to an event, since you already used the timer one ini your code ;)

Comment: Thanks, this and a tweak to the arduino code fixed the issue. The arduino code had a function querying for the rotation of the fan, and the default timeout was 1 second, and getting the RPM from 12 fans took a while. And the C# code was trying to run code on nothing which was causing the slowdown.